# spin cpu for 1 second in Linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I know if i call sleep(1) in Linux, the processor performs context switch and brings back the process into memory after 1 second.

Is there any API which spins for 1 second without leaving the CPU.

Comment: Why would there be? You can make one yourself if you really need to, but there are much cheaper ways to heat rooms than with CPUs.

Comment: Intel have spent the last 30 years making it really hard that you don't do this, by including multiple cpus and longer and longer pipelines.  Remember, you probably have 4 or more 'CPU's in your computer, do you want to 'spin' them all (and what do you /really/ mean by 'spin')

Comment: Spin one cpu for 1 sec

Comment: If Liinux, Intel, or whoever, started including API calls that might, possibly, maybe, be of some use to 0.0000001% of developers writing some dodgy real-time app on a general-purpose OS, then incompetent and/or unconcerned bad developers would just use it out-of-hand, writing apps that needlessly waste silicon on garbage loops and, as @Art says above, raise a/c bills everywhere:(

Comment: Noted.. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Also, 'brings back the process into memory' no, code/data for a thread that is blocked is not guaranteed to be removed from memory.  Execution is withheld, sure, but there is no need to page out memory if it is not needed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such standard API. No competent programmer would provide such an API in a normal computer system, as it is wasteful.

If you are trying to accomplish some other goal, such as ensuring certain data stays in memory, there may be other ways to accomplish it, such as `mlock`.